# Continuity on the overlap in pasting lemma when not both sets are closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

The pasting lemma states the following for a function $f\colon X\to Y$ ($X$, $Y$ topological spaces):

> If $X$ can be decomposed as a union of two closed sets $F_1$ and $F_2$ on each of which $f$'s restriction is continuous, then $f$ is continuous.

The necessity of the sets being all closed is usually shown by considering examples of the following flavours:

1. *$F_1$ and $F_2$ are taken to be disjoint:* For instance, taking $F_1 := (-\infty, 0]$ and $F_2:= (0, +\infty)$ and defining $f\colon \mathbb {R\to R}$ by $f(x) := 0$ if $x\le 0$ and $f(x) := 1/x$ otherwise.
2. *Even if $F_1\cap F_2\ne\emptyset$, the example is continuous on the overlap:* For instance, taking $F_1 := \mathbb Q$ and $F_2 := (\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\cup\{0\}$ with $f\colon\mathbb{R\to R}$ given by $f(x) := 0$ if $x\in F_1$ and $f(x) := x$ if $x\in F_2$.

**Question:** Can we have an example so that $f$ is discontinuous *in the overlap*?

Comment: We cannot if the space is sufficiently "nice". In particular, we cannot have this for metric spaces. If continuity is characterize by sequences, then we can decompose the sequence into one part in $F_1$ and the other part in $F_2$. However, if we are in the overlap, then $f$ will converge to $f_1(x_0)=f_2(x_0)$ and hence, the function will be continuous at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot happen for spaces where continuity is characterized by sequences (e.g. in metric spaces). For $j\in \{1,2\}$ let sequences $(x_n^{(j)})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq F_j$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n^{(j)}=x$. As $f_j$ is continuous on $F_j$, we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_j(x_n^{(j)})=f_j(x).$$ However, if $x\in F_1\cap F_2$, then $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$. As $F_1\cup F_2=X$, we get that for every $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n=x$ that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)=f(x)$$ which (by assumption) implies that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

In fact this can never happen. Pick $x\in F_1\cap F_2$ and pick some neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ in $Y$. As $f_1, f_2$ are continuous, there exist open nbhds $x\in U_j\subseteq X$ such that $$U_j\cap F_j\subseteq f_j^{-1}(V).$$
Then $U=U_1\cap U_2$ is an open nbhd of $x$ in $X$ and we have
$$ U= (U\cap F_1)\cup (U\cap F_2)\subseteq f_1^{-1}(V)\cup f_2^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(V).$$ Thus, $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I think "yes" as we can define continuity in point. And this is example of function continious in one point despite definition in whole real line

Comment: Yes, I know about continuity at a point. And yes, the second example in my post is continuous only at one point (namely, 0) despite being defined on the whole of $\mathbb R$. But how does that answer my question?